# Custom Transformer using BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand if transformation on `X_train` in the code below is done in place:

```
# Custom transformer for creating new attributes by combining existing attributes
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

total_rooms_idx, households_idx, population_idx, total_bedrooms_idx = 3, 6, 5, 4

class AttributesAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, add_bedrooms_per_room = True):
        self.add_bedrooms_per_room = add_bedrooms_per_room
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self    # Nothing to do in fit in this scenario
    
    def transform(self, X):           
        X['rooms_per_household'] = X.iloc[:, total_rooms_idx] / X.iloc[:, households_idx]
        X['population_per_household'] = X.iloc[:, population_idx] / X.iloc[:, households_idx]
        
        if self.add_bedrooms_per_room:
            X['bedrooms_per_room'] = X.iloc[:, total_bedrooms_idx] / X.iloc[:, total_rooms_idx]
        
        return X


obj = AttributesAdder()
obj.transform(X_train)

print(X_train)
```

I'm not storing the return value from transform function but still X_train is modified. Is this transformation done in place? Is this functionality adopted from base classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you edit in `transform` is a dataframe that you access through the variable X. Unless you make a copy of this dataframe, the operations are inplace. Also, there is no need to return anything from the function.

I created a short example to answer your question.

```py
class AttributesAdder():
    def transform(self, X):
        X['A'] = 2
        X['B'] = 3

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

obj = AttributesAdder()
obj.transform(df)
```

The output will be:

```py
    A   B
0   2   3
1   2   3
2   2   3
```

Here is another example using a view of a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df_view = df
obj.transform(df_view)

df
    A   B
0   2   3
1   2   3
2   2   3
```

As you can see, passing a view of the dataframe through `transform` will also transform your original dataframe. You can see variables storing dataframes like addresses.

If you don't want this behavior, you need to make a copy of your original dataframe using `new_df = df.copy()`

Comment: Thanks. If anyone looking to avoid this case, df_view = df.copy(). df_view is a new copy of df and they both won't point to same reference, hence changing one doesn't impact other